# Get response back from unpingable websites (C# ASP .net mvc)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ping, arp

I'm not a network expert, but for one of my projects, I need to ensure that the website I'm sending the request to is alive. Some websites do not respond to ping; basically, their configuration prevents response to ping requests.
I was trying to [Arping](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.sendarp) instead of pinging websites, but Arping only works on the local network and will not go beyond the network segment ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132941/arp-request-in-c-sharp)).
I can download the whole or part of the webpage and confirm if the content is the same as the previous state, but I rather have one more level of confirmation before downloading Html.

Is there any other method that enables the app to get a response back from non-pingable websites outside the network?

Answer (score 0):

Based on common practices you may use ping, telnet and tracert as a client to the requested server (at this point the website or the service you want to connect) and make sure the 3 command are enable to your side. You may also try to access it to your browser.

If its API you may also try to use POSTMAN and call the service.

Goodluck and happy coding :)